# Initialize multi-level pointer to pointer and compile error occurs

Tags: c++, c, pointers, gcc, compilation

I have multi-level pointer to pointer code like this:

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int a = 1;
        int *pa = &a;
        //int **ppa = &pa; // [Right Code]
        int **ppa = &&a; // [Wrong Code]
        int ***pppa = &ppa;

        *ppa = pa;
        **pppa = pa;
        *pppa = &pa;
}
```

When using gcc to compile,this line "int **ppa = &&a;" fails.

> ⋊> /h/m/stackoverfolw gcc test4.c
> test4.c: In function 'main':
> test4.c:7:2: error: label 'a' used but not defined
> int **ppa = &&a;
> ^

Could somebody tell me whether we cannot intialize pointer to pointer with value type and 2-level symbol '&'?

Comment: Addresses don't have addresses. Your pointer, which holds an address as its value, does. If I live on 123 Some St., what would you say my address's address is?

Comment: To further illustrate, suppose we did `int a = 1; int *p_int = &a; int** pp_int = &p_int; int b = 2; p_int = &b; pp_int = &p_int;`. Should the value of `pp_int` change here? After all, `b` is different from `a`, so if we were really taking "the address of the address of `a`", it should be different. But `pp_int` is not the address of the address of `a`, it's the address of `p_int`, a variable which used to hold the address of `a` and now doesn't. The address of `p_int` hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's incorrect syntax in both C and C++. Step back a bit and think what would an *address of address* mean. @sweenish has provided an excellent example of that in real life. I'll resort to a bit of assembly.

```
int a = 1;
int *pa = &a;
```

This translates to assembly something on the lines of

```
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 1
    lea     rax, [rbp-12]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
```

The first `mov` instruction is just assigning the value of 1 to the memory at `rbp - 12` which, as one can guess, is assembly corresponding to `a = 1;` This tells that value of `a`'s memory address is `rbp - 12` since that is what is used to write the value of 1 to. The next instruction `lea` essentially means that _get the address of whatever is in the memory at `rbp - 12` , which, as can be guessed, is actually `rbp - 12`! (i.e. the address of `a` given by `&a`) and store that address in `rax`. The next instruction is just moving this value of `rax` to a memory location at `rbp - 8` which corresponds to seting the value of the variable `pa`. Now if there was some syntax to support a statement like `int **ppa = &&a` that would mean taking the address of the value of `rbp -12` which doesn't make sense because taking address of actual values doesn't make sense. It would be somewhat similar to writing something akin to `int *pa = &0xdeadbeef;`. You have a a variable `a`, it's address in the memory `&a`(which is just a plain number) and then another variable that stores that address `pa`.